# Proof of the isomorphism of the Toeplitz algebra and the algebra generated by the element and the relation

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras, operator-theory, c-star-algebras, toeplitz-operators

Please tell me where can I see the proof of this well-known fact?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kWM2C.png)

Comment: Not sure where to find the proof. But by universality of your universal $C^{\ast}$-algerba there exists a homomorphism of $C^{\ast}(G,R)\to \mathcal T$, where $\mathcal T$ is the  Toeplitz algebra, since $\mathcal T$ has a single generator this homorphism is surjective , injectivity of the homomorphism requires a bit more work but is somewhat easy to see.

Comment: You should find this in Murphy's book on "C*-algebras and operator theory"